# Use Laravel Livewire with Laravel Fortify for Login

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-fortify

I'm wanting to use Laravel Fortify and Livewire to create a very simple login form. I do not want to use Jetstream as it has more features that I do not need vs features I do need.

I'm using livewire throughout my app, and would like to use it for my login page to provide real time instant validation.

The problem I am encountering is I am unable to submit the form with values if I'm using `wire:model` on inputs.

I also can not use `auth()->attempt()` because it is being hijacked by Fortify.(At least, I think it is. All know is when I use it, it returns `false`)

How can I use livewire with fortify? I need to send the data from the livewire component to `POST /login`.

Here is my current set up:

`FortifyServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
    {
        Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
        Fortify::updateUserProfileInformationUsing(UpdateUserProfileInformation::class);
        Fortify::updateUserPasswordsUsing(UpdateUserPassword::class);
        Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);

        // Custom Fortify Views =============================

        // Login Page
        Fortify::loginView(function () {
            return view('auth.login');
        });
   }
```

My `auth/login.blade.php` (simply calls the livewire components with the proper layout template)

```
<x-layouts.auth>
    @livewire('auth.login')
</x-layouts.auth>
```

The livewire component `livewire/auth/login.blade.php`:

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="login" action="#" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input wire:model="email" id="email" type="email" required autofocus>
        @error('email'){{ $message }}@enderror
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input wire:model.lazy="password" id="password" type="password" required>
        @error('password'){{ $message }}@enderror
    </div>

    <div>
        <input wire:model.lazy="remember" id="remember_me" type="checkbox">
        <label for="remember_me">Remember me</label>

        <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and my `Http/Livewire/Auth/Login.php` file for the livewire component:

```
class Login extends Component
{
    public $email = '';
    public $password = '';
    public $remember = false;

    protected $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email|exists:users,email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ];

    /**
     * Shows Real time validation for email field
     */
    public function updatedEmail() {
        $this->validate(['email' => 'email|exists:users,email']);
    }

    /**
     * Logs user in when form is submitted
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Support\MessageBag
     */
    public function login()
    {
        // ******* Need to submit the form to Fortify here?? ******
    }

    /**
     * Renders the view
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.auth.login')
            ->layout('layouts.auth');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> class Login extends Component
> {
>   public $email = '';
>   public $password = '';
> ......
> ```

First of all, accoring to the [Livewire documentation](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#important-notes), sensitive information(such as passwords) SHOULD NOT BE used as public properties in livewire components. Therefore you should think twice before using livewire with user authentication.

> ```
> protected $rules = [
>   'email' => 'required|email|exists:users,email',
>   'password' => 'required',
> ];
> ```

Next, in validation rules you are using *exists:user,email* which would validate real-time if an email is in the database. I would advice against using this validation with livewire real-time validation rule in production systems as it could be easily used by a malicious actor to extract email list of users of your system.


That being said, there are ways for you to authenticate(but not using Fortify) inside you login function. for example:

```
class LoginForm extends Component
{
public $email = '';
public $password = '';
public $remember = false;

protected $rules = [
    'email' => 'required|email|exists:users,email',
    'password' => 'required',
];

/*

Sometimes it's useful to validate a form field as a user types into it. 
Livewire makes "real-time" validation simple with the $this->validateOnly() method.

To validate an input field after every update, we can use Livewire's updated hook:

 */
public function updated($propertyName)
{
    $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.loginForm');
}

public function login()
{
    $this->validate();

    // Execution doesn't reach here if validation fails.

    $email = $this->email;
    $password = $this->password;
    $credentials = ['email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password];

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Auth success
    }

    else{
        // Auth failed
    }
}
```

}

Then again, when using this method, you are only using *Fortify* to retrieve the login page which is definitely not the intended use of *Fortify*. Therefore after considering all the issues, I think it is best you avoid using livewire for user authentication process.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the security implications and the reasoing why the authentication is done using traditional POST forms in Fortify. 
I which this was explained in the documentation of Fortify.

Comment: @codingFriend1 Did you target me in this comment?

Comment: @AliAli No not at all, unless it was you who wrote the Jetstream docs (but in that case it was not meant as an offense but as a kind suggestion) I actually appreciate your answer to the question a lot and also upvoted it. I just think the security considerations weigh heavier than the actual solution.
Also, in my comment above I actually meant the Jetstream for LiveWire docs not the Fortify docs.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to install a new project with only Livewire and Fortify to simulate your scenario.
After a long pondering, these are my findings

1. It's the most confusing part when I saw the login() method and
   started to think that this method will handle the authentication or
   forward it or something.
2. Fortify uses its own routs, so you can't do the authentication without
   sending your form data to the "/login" endpoint.
3. Your livewire component will help with showing the real-time
   validation errors, (maybe you can disable the form submit button
   until the validation passes).
4. Let Fortify handle the authentication for you and set your form to
   submit

> `<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">`

5. If you need to customize the authentication process, Fortify offers
   you this feature easily, see the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#customizing-user-authentication)
6. If you insist to use the login() method I think you can create a PHP POST
   request to send the fields, but I can't see the point in doing that.

I hope this will give you the idea.

Comment: So in the end, you cannot use a full page LiveWire component for the login page but would instead just include single LiveWire components (like the form itself with dynamic error output) into the regular login blade view and still submit the form as a regular POST.
I guess the entire thing is only confusing because Jetstream has a LiveWire edition using Fortify but in fact Fortify obviously is not built with LiveWire in mind. So also Jetstream uses regular full page views for the login.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, quite confusing but this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I add route in web.php as follow:

```
Route::get('/login',Login::class)->middleware('guest')->name('login');
```

that Login::class is a livewire component where path is App\Http\Livewire\Auth\Login .
In livewire/auth/login.blade.php exist a form by action as:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}"> .... </form>
```

that route('login') by post method is related to Fortify.